# Curl and Potential of Vectorfields.

Tags: integration, vectors, vector-analysis

(-y,x) is a vector$$f_a(x,y) = \frac {1}{(x^2+y^2)^a}(-y,x)$$

After using the curl or rotation formula i get:
for $a = 0$ and $a = 1$ there is constant curl or rotation. For the latter the Curl is 0 but the Function does not have a Potential.

Now my problem is to calculate  Potential $u$ and $v$ such that this function is defined in $$\{(x,y)\in R^2| x,y \neq 0\}$$

How do i go about this because as you can see from the values of "$a$" there is no Potential function. Or am i suppose to take a value for $a$ that makes this as a potential function and then work on it? please advice.

Comment: What does $(-y,x)$ at the end mean? Is it $(-yx)$ ?

And how do you know that for $a=1$ a potential doesn't exist? Have you tried calculating it and failed?

Comment: I don't understand what the question is. For what $a$ do you want to calculate a potential function?